# Find next lower value in list of (float) numbers?

Tags: python, python-2.6

How should I write the `find_nearest_lower` function?

```
>>> values = [10.1, 10.11, 10.20]
>>> my_value = 10.12
>>> nearest_lower = find_nearest_lower(values, my_value)
>>> nearest_lower
10.11
```

This needs to work in Python 2.6 without access to numpy.

Comment: is values always sorted?

Comment: Yeah, you can use the code from muzido's link and just skip the `abs` to make it sensitive to "nearest lower" or "nearest upper" instead of just "nearest".

Comment: @depperm yes, they're always sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> def find_nearest_lower(seq, x):
...     return max(item for item in seq if item < x)
...
>>> values = [10.1, 10.11, 10.20]
>>> my_value = 10.12
>>> nearest_lower = find_nearest_lower(values, my_value)
>>> nearest_lower
10.11
```

This approach will raise an exception if there aren't any values in `seq` that are smaller than `x`. If this is undesirable behavior, you could instead return a sentinel value, such as None:

```
def find_nearest_lower(seq, x):
    candidates = [item for item in seq if item < x]
    if not candidates: return None
    return max(candidates)
```

Or

```
def find_nearest_lower(seq, x):
    try:
        return max(item for item in seq if item < x)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

... If you're more of an "ask forgiveness" person than a "look before you leap" person.

Comment: I think there's an argument here that raising an exception when the list doesn't contain any values lower than x, is an acceptable design choice. Regardless, if you'd prefer that it returns a value signaling nothing was found, you could do `return max([item for item in seq if item < x], default=None)`

Comment: Ooh, actually, looks like the `default` keyword isn't present in 2.7 and lower... I better write an alternative. One moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> values = [10.1, 10.11, 10.20]
>>> my_value = 10.12
>>> next(dropwhile(lambda x: x > my_value, sorted(values, reverse=True)))
10.11
```

You can also pass a `default` argument to [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) which will be returned if the iterator is exhausted instead of raising `StopIteration`.